# How can I get my memory card slot to work?

Tags: drivers, dell, sd-card, xps, card-reader

I use Ubuntu 12.10, on Dell L702x, and the internal memory card slot has never functioned since I switched from its original Windows 7 installation. I've had to use my usb reader for a while now.

How can I get it working, what drivers should I install?

Comment: Did it work in Windows, Some Dell notebook BIOS have a setting for that, do you have it enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Yes it worked on Windows, and now thanks to @Web-E's answer, it now works on Ubuntu. However, I need a way to make the changes permanent, so I don't have to run the command every time I start the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert card in memory card slot, then execute

`sudo su -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan'`.

This was a problem with my L502x and in 12.04. I have not tested it for 12.10

Comment: This worked! However, I have to execute that command every time I start the system. Is there a way to make it permanent?

Comment: Open dash, type: Startup Applications. Click add. Type something in the name box then in the command box type the command from above. Click ok.